# Is there a function for preventing a user from inputing while a function is running?

Tags: c

I made a program that has a delay between functions, and while the program works, the user is able to interfere and type characters while the program is running.

The program prints out characters of a string, one at a time, with a 0.1 second delay, but while the string is printing, the user can interfere by typing in and between the letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void delay(unsigned int milliseconds){
    clock_t start = clock();
    while((clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < milliseconds);
    }

void text (int br, char sentence []){
    int c = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < br; c++){
        printf("%c", sentence[c]);
        fflush(stdout);
        delay (100);
        }
    }

int main(){
text (15,"Hello friends!\n");
}
```

I would like to see the text being printed out without the possibility of any interference between the delays.

Comment: At the start of the program print "Charging the keyboard to 500V..."

Comment: With no threads lurking, the code you have would be sufficient.  Blocking and non-blocking functions will determine whether interruptions can occur.  But you are not operating in a thread free environment.  The OS uses event handlers (in this case HID routines) that are just sitting there waiting for something to handle, even with your `delay` statement.

Comment: @stark I hope for the computer it is a wireless keyboard ^^

Comment: What Operating system ???

Comment: iOS, working on a mac

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible to do in a portable way. If you're on Linux, you can have a look at the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library.

If you are happy with just disabling the output and are on a POSIX-system you can do like this:

```
void text (int br, char sentence []){
    system("stty -echo");

    /* Your previous code */

    system("stty echo");
}
```

And if you also want to clear stdin from anything that was typed when that function was running:

```
void text (int br, char sentence []){
    system("stty -echo");

    /* Your previous code */

    int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);        
    system("stty echo");
}
```

The cursor can be made invisible with `system("setterm -cursor off");`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works! But is there a way to remove the key icon that is at the end of every letter that is typed out? Also I am working on a Mac if that helps out.

Comment: @TheSnoze I added info about cursor

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it only disables the cursors that are not locked, the one that is locked with system("stty -echo")/system("stty echo") is not disabled, it still has the 'key' icon while it is typed out